# Finding the coin that is not the same weight as the rest proof. Can someone check my work?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

```
You have a pile of N coins and there is one coin in the pile that is either 
lighter or heavier than the rest. You have a scale that is expensive with 
time use, so you want to be conservative with your weighing. Write a  
recursive algorithm and find the time complexity.
```

Here is my answer:

```
1. Split the pile of n coins into 4 different piles
2. Weigh each pile and eliminate the 3 piles which are the same weight, but 
   keep a single coin from an eliminated pile for comparison (Call it "c"
3. Repeat this process recursively for the remaining pile
4. When down to the last 2 coins, whichever coin is a different weight than
   coin "c" is the odd coin in the pile.

T(N) = T(N/4) + c
O(logN)
```

Is this correct?

Comment: It seems like your algorithm assumes the 4 piles would have equal coin count.

Comment: aw man :( I knew something was wrong

Comment: Well, see if you can get something out of cutting $N$ into $x+x+x+x+e$ where $e$ is only $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$.

Comment: A classic question like this involves a balance scale, where you don't get a numerical weight from a measurement, but rather get to balance one pile against another and see which is possibly heavier. Is this question like that or is it about a scale where you can record a numerical weight for one pile?